# Android: Camera2 capturing image

Tags: android, image-capture, android-camera2

I was trying to capture a photo using this [sample](https://github.com/pinguo-yuyidong/Camera2/tree/master/camera2) using both front and back camera, which is done inside this [fragment](https://github.com/pinguo-yuyidong/Camera2/blob/master/camera2/src/main/java/us/yydcdut/camera2/ui/PreviewFragment.java) .

Obviuosly the onCaptureCompleted is called after each capture, so I wanted to get that picture from "TotalCaptureResult result" but I coudn't, also it seem's that the onCaptureCompleted is never called when I try to take a picture with the front camera.

So how to get the captured image from both front and back camera? any help or hint is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't do this as cameras on different devices might not have support for it. android is fragmented and camera behaviour differs amony devices.

for one camera you can do this :
[Capture Image from Camera and Display in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity)

Answer (score 0):

[Try this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545144/camera-intent-data-null-in-onactivityresultint-requestcode-int-resultcode-int)

In OnactivityResult you will get your image.